# how to transfer Entry information in tkinter to a list

Tags: python, list, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('sorter')
# funktion for new entry sorter
number = 0
entry_information_list = []
def new_entry():
    global number
    global entry_information_list
    number += 1
    # number
    number_of_name = Label(root, text=number, width=20)
    number_of_name.grid(row=number, column=0)
    #entry feeld
    new_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=3, width=100)
    new_entry.grid(row=number, column=1, columnspan=4)

    entry_information_list.append(new_entry.get())
    print(entry_information_list)

#buttons
number_for_list = Button(root, text='Sort by number', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_1_name = Button(root, text='Sort by first name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_2_name = Button(root, text='Sort by second name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_3_name = Button(root, text='Sort by third name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
new_entry_button = Button(root, text='New entry', borderwidth=3, command=new_entry, width=20)

#position and description of buttons
number_for_list.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_for_1_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_for_2_name.grid(row=0, column=2)
button_for_3_name.grid(row=0, column=3)
new_entry_button.grid(row=0, column=4)


root.mainloop()
```

When I try to see what information is in the list from the consol it shows that it is filled with empty elements. am i missin a line or do i use a compleatly different structure?

Comment: you are getting the information from entry about a millisecond after you `.grid` it so user won't have the chance of entering anything into it. You have to have maybe another button or sth else like a binding that will `.get` data from `Entry` and store it inside the list, also you don't need `global entry_information_list`

Comment: @Ruggero they do it with the button, besides they have clearly stated that the list simply has empty strings

Comment: Thanks. just realised the same thing. I think when it creates the new entry it append it before any information is added and when the button is pressed it moves on and does the same

Comment: @Ruggero that is also incorrect, `.sleep` freezes the script so it won't continue past that function until it has ended (it will also visibly freeze the GUI
), I suggest that you research what event-driven programming is, as this is exactly that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
entry_information_list.append(new_entry.get())
```

You are calling `new_entry.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget, far before the user has seen the widget much less had time to type into it.

Instead, you should be appending the widget itself:

```
entry_information_list.append(new_entry)
```

Later, when you are ready to process the data, a simple list comprehension will get all the data from all of the widgets:

```
data = [widget.get() for widget in entry_information_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve this is to bind the newly created entry to for example enter key (return key) and have a function that will get data from that entry and append it to the list:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry


root = Tk()
root.title('sorter')

# function for new entry sorter
number = 0
entry_information_list = []


def append_data(event=None):
    data = event.widget.get()
    entry_information_list.append(data)
    print(entry_information_list)


def new_entry():
    global number
    number += 1
    # number
    number_of_name = Label(root, text=number, width=20)
    number_of_name.grid(row=number, column=0)

    # entry field
    entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=3, width=100)
    entry.grid(row=number, column=1, columnspan=4)
    entry.bind('<Return>', append_data)


# buttons
number_for_list = Button(root, text='Sort by number', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_1_name = Button(root, text='Sort by first name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_2_name = Button(root, text='Sort by second name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
button_for_3_name = Button(root, text='Sort by third name', borderwidth=3, width=20)
new_entry_button = Button(root, text='New entry', borderwidth=3, command=new_entry, width=20)

# position and description of buttons
number_for_list.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_for_1_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_for_2_name.grid(row=0, column=2)
button_for_3_name.grid(row=0, column=3)
new_entry_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

A few downsides are that if you press the return key multiple times, the same value will get appended twice so maybe use a set or a dictionary or index to replace the previous value. Then also you have to press return key each time and be in the correct entry. But otherwise at least you get the idea: you need an event to happen that will get data from entry, otherwise as in your case it happens almost immediately without giving the user a chance to enter any data.